# What condition do I put to further add a 5% discount?

Tags: c++

The amount to be paid is normally calculated by multiplying the unit price by the quantity sold. However, the following applies:

- If the quantity sold is greater than or equal to the price-break quantity, then a 10% discount is
  given for that item.
- If a discount is given, and the new amount to be paid exceeds $1000.00, then a further 5%
  discount is given.
- If a discount is not given, and the amount to be paid exceeds $1000.00, then a 5% discount is
  given

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int items;
    int i=0;
    int item_num;
    double unit_price;
    double price_break;
    double quantity_sold;
    double amount_paid;
    double discount=0.00;
    double net_payment;

    amount_paid=unit_price*quantity_sold;
    if(quantity_sold>=price_break){
        discount=0.1*amount_paid;
        new_amount=amount_paid-discount
        //Quantity sold is more than price break which places discount at 10%
        net_payment=new_amount;         
    }else{
        //Need help with this. How do I further add 5%?
        if((quantity_sold>=price_break)&&(new_amount>1000)){
            discount=0.1*amount_paid;
            net_payment=amount_paid-discount;
        }
        else{
            if(amount_paid>1000){
                // discount is 5% since the amount to be paid exceeds $1000
                discount=0.05*amount_paid;
                net_payment=amount_paid-discount;
            }
            else{
                if(quantity_sold<price_break){
                    //No discount and the amount to be paid doesn't exceeds $1000
                    net_payment=amount_paid;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The current code is missing a few braces and some lines at the top.  Is this the best [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can provide?

Comment: @FOrde Can you list the type of the variables in the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the second and third conditions result in the same thing happening, you can simplify the rules as follows:

1. First, if the quantity sold is greater than or equal to the price-break quantity, then a 10% discount is given for that item.
2. Regardless of whether or not a discount was given in step 1, a 5% discount is given if the amount to be paid is over $1,000.

So just get rid of the `else` block in the outer `if` and instead just test if the amount is over $1,000.

```
amount_paid=unit_price*quantity_sold;
if(quantity_sold>=price_break){
// apply first discount if quantity is high enough
    discount=0.1*amount_paid;
    amount_paid-=discount;
}
if(amount_paid>1000){
// discount is 5% since the amount to be paid exceeds $1000
    discount=0.05*amount_paid;
    amount_paid-=discount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to check if the price exceeds 1000 no matter whether the first condition is met, the second and the third condition can actually be merged into one:

If after the first condition is processed, the price exceeds 1000, apply 5% discount.

```
auto calculate_discount(double unit_price, double quality_sold, double price_break)
{
    auto price = unit_price * quality_sold;

    // The first discount
    if (quantity_sold >= price_break) 
        price *= 0.9;

    // The second
    if (price > 1000.0)
        price *= 0.95;

    return price;
}
```